# Android Project Not Building Correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I had a project working fine, now whenever I try to build/run I get the following exception:

```
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kicker.android.kickstart/com.kicker.android.kickstart.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kicker.android.kickstart.HomeActivity" on path: /data/app/com.kicker.android.kickstart-1.apk
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kicker.android.kickstart.HomeActivity" on path: /data/app/com.kicker.android.kickstart-1.apk
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-08 18:11:04.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    ... 11 more
```

The relevant portion of my manifest file is:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/KickStartTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kicker.android.kickstart.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I know that this problem is usually a type in the manifest, where the main activity name is incorrect.  I have double checked that portion.

And here is the really weird part, I have been developing this application on two different computers.   If I build on computer "A", and launch the app, it works fine.  If I export the project from computer "A" and import it into a clean workspace on computer "B"  without making any other changes, I will get the above error on launch of the app.

What could be causing this on computer "B"?

Comment: Are you on the latest ADT (v 22) and using any libraries (eg the google provided support library)? If so, make sure that `Android Private Libraries` is also checked in the `Order and Export` section of the `Java Build Bath` for this project.

Comment: Yes, ADT 22.  I am using the google support library and the facebook sdk.  Android Private Libraries (and the support library) were NOT checked under order and export.   I checked them, did a clean/build, and still have the same problem.  EDIT:  Actually that did work!  Thanks!  If you want to change your comment to the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Name your acitivty ".HomeActivity" as below and you should be good to you.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Fully qualified or .HomeActivity, both generate the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If You run on ADT v 22 You must install android sdk build-tools and Android SDK Platform-tools

Open SDK Manager - Tools - install "android sdk build-tools" and "Android SDK Platform-tools"

I get same error after upgrade ADT from v.21 to v.22 after install android sdk build-tools and Android SDK Platform-tools, everything is ok.

(Check it at AVD Manager)